# Is it feasible to alter the CPU ID through the utilization of software?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-detection, software-activation

I am considering implementing a method for ensuring the integrity of the activation/trial period of my software, by tying it to the unique fingerprint of the user's machine. After conducting research, I have determined that the most reliable option for this purpose would be to obtain the identifier of a hardware component that is highly unlikely to be altered, such as the motherboard or CPU. However, I have encountered information suggesting that obtaining the motherboard identifier may not always be feasible, and thus, resorting to the CPU identifier may be the only option available. Before I proceed with investing resources into this security strategy, I would like to inquire about the feasibility of an average computer user altering the CPU identifier, particularly if they are aware that this identifier is linked to the activation of my software, and changing it would result in a reset of the trial period. Would it be a safe bet to rely on the CPU identifier for the purpose of software security?

Comment: @Ramhound If the CPU ID changes due to actions by CPU manufacturers, I am not concerned. My focus is on determining whether knowledgeable PC users can alter the CPU ID. The hardware ID is not used for licensing purposes and does not make the licensing process difficult for customers. My aim is to prevent users from resetting trials, which has no relation to verifying valid licenses.

Comment: @Ramhound I have gathered this information through my research. The question remains if there are readily available tools that allow users to easily change the CPU ID. Based on my search results, I have not come across any threads or tools that make it clear that changing the CPU ID is easy. However, I might not have searched in the right places, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: Running the software on a VM would make modifying CPU data trivial.

Comment: @music2myear yes, but I can easily detect when software is running under a VM and I don't intend to offer trial periods to such instances, so I'm really only concerned about physical systems.